# How do I get rid of the space that belongs to the header, in pages where I don't need it?

Tags: spacing, header-footer

So, I'm writting a document in `article` class, and I need a header only in the first page wich contains an image. This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhead[L]{Left Text}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics{image.jpg}}
\setlength{\headheight}{54pt}

\title{Document}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the size of image by `\includegraphics[width=5mm, height=5mm]{image.jpg}`

Comment: In general, \smash any images added to fancyhdr.